# ConstraintLayout on small screen (simple)

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

As you can see, on the small screen the last TextView is cropped to the right.
Here's how it looks:

[image]

I need it to be so:

[image]

Here is the layout source code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text:"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="1234567890.1234567890"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that with a `ConstraintLayout`. You could create another xml layout file for small screens that fit your needs

Comment: I think what you need is a Flow Layout. That is not supported natively but you find some libraries, ([for example this](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)) that implements it

Comment: @Pelocho https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout is better

Comment: Yes, it's probably better. There are a lot of libraries that do that and there probably are lots of them that do it better than the one I provided. That's why I said "for example"

Answer (score 0):

for this issue you may have to create new custom xml file layout click on LayoutVariant option in design view like above

[image: select]

then select option - Create Other.. at end 
Now set Directory Name as custom and select option Available qualifiers now set dimension 480 and 800 as like above

[image: new]

now set texView2 below textView like below

[image: da]